# Image compression java

Tags: java, networking

I want to transfer Images via network socket(java.net).Where Can I find a sample Code for

compressing Buffered Images in java..Say for example If my Image file is around 200kb,I want

it to be converted to atleat 100kb..So that the transfer will be lil bit fast..

Thank you..

Comment: Image files like jpeg, png are already compressed. There is little chance that you can further compress them.

Comment: @Nishan: I believe `BufferedImage` is uncompressed in memory, even if it's read from a source that was compressed.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 You are right.  I was thinking of sending files across, than sending BufferedImages.

Comment: Since BufferedImage doesn't implement Serializable interface,I am converting it to ImageIcon & putting it to ObjectOutputStream,So that the server can read the image..Transfer time is the issue because my screenshots are around 197kb each..I want that to be reduced & transmitted..

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge the best compression without loss on images is done with PNG which the image libraries in Java can write.

If you need smaller images than that you need to use lossy compression.  A simple way to do that is with JPEG, where you can turn down the quality until you get the rate you want.

You could also downscale the images first to 1/2 or 1/3 of the original dimensions givning a much smaller picture and transfer that, and upscale it in the other end.  That will be usable for quick transfers, and you can then transfer a full image when the movements have settled down.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that really depend of what you want to do.

If you want to transfer image as the expend of some loss of quality, you can save them to JPEG (in a memory stream), transfer theses byte data and read the image again on the other side. A typical 200KB image could be reduced to 20-50K with a good resulting quality.

Reading [The Java Image I/O API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/imageio_guideTOC.fm.html) could help for that.

If you absolutely want to preserve the original bytes, or want a more generic solution, just use some compression library like Gzip to compress/decompress your data. To get you started you can use [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) as a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ImageIO.write()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to stream a `BufferedImage` in a supported image format that's compressed, e.g. `jpg` (lossy compression) or `png` (lossless compression).